# How do I replace all columns with brackets around them?

Tags: regex, replace, find, ssms

**NOTE** - In case anyone missed the tags, I'm using regex in the Find and Replace tool in SSMS 2012.

So I have this query:

```
SELECT [name]
      ,[categories]
FROM [TEST_QUERIES].[dbo].[TestForCSV]
```

And I would like to change it to:

```
SELECT replace([name], ',', '|')
      ,replace([categories], ',', '|')
  FROM [TEST_QUERIES].[dbo].[TestForCSV]
```

I tried

```
find what: {\[*\]}
replace with: replace(\0, ',', '|')
```

But that didn't work. So what is the regex to make this work?

**EDIT**
So after reading @SO post and reading [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), I now have this:

```
find what: {\[.*\]}
replace with: replace(\0, ',', '|')
```

and this

```
find what: {\[:w\]}
replace with: replace(\0, ',', '|')
```

Problem is that they give me

```
replace([TEST_QUERIES].[dbo].[TestForCSV], ',', '|')
```

and

```
[TEST_QUERIES].replace([dbo], ',', '|').replace([TestForCSV], ',', '|')
```

respectively.

I only want what's after the SELECT but before the FROM changed.

Answer (score 1):

`/[\[][\w]+[\]]/` will match any word in square brackets.

Breakdown:

the first and last `/` are delimiters, the pattern is as follows:

`[\[]` will match a single opening square bracket `[`

`[\w]+` will match one or more letters of a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _ ('\w' is a shorthand expression for these groups of characters)

`[\]]` will match a single closing square bracket `]`

in regex, square brackets are a special character used to match a single instance of anything between the brackets, and so we have to use a backslash `\` to escape the 'square bracket within a square bracket'

`[[]` or `[]]` would not work.

In summary, the pattern used says "Match an opening square bracket `[`, then match any amount/combination of `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or `_` and finally match a closed square bracket `]`."

`/[\[][\w]+[\]]/` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

**EDIT:** *further request for look-behind feature*

`/(?<!FROM |[.])[\[][\w]+[\]]/gmi`

This pattern will match according to your example, but may not be suitable for the other parameters in your code. The pattern uses a function called 'lookbehind' which isn't supported by all regex engines.

You can see how this pattern is working here: http://regex101.com/r/eP6nS4/2

This should give you the information you need to understand how the pattern is working and how to amend it.

Comment: it may be beneficial to break down exactly what the regex is doing.

Comment: When I run this regex in SSMS 2012, I get the following error: `The following specified text was not found`. And yes, I have `Use: Regular Expressions` checked.

Comment: I don't think regex in VS supports the look-behind feature, so it may not be possible. I don't know what regex type SSMS uses, but I'll amend my post in case it does work.